# Angular ng-class need help setting up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

Alright so I am trying to get my css background to change colors based on ng-class value of true or false but I don't know if I am doing this right.

```
<div id="home">
```

### Summoner

```
         <div id="information" ng-repeat="match in matches | limitTo: 10">
        <img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.9.1/img/champion/{{ champions[match.championId]}}.png"  />
        <img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.9.1/img/item/{{match.stats.item0}}.png"/>
        <img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.9.1/img/item/{{match.stats.item1}}.png"/>
        <img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.9.1/img/item/{{match.stats.item2}}.png"/>
        <img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.9.1/img/item/{{match.stats.item3}}.png"/>
        <img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.9.1/img/item/{{match.stats.item4}}.png"/>
        <img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.9.1/img/item/{{match.stats.item5}}.png"/>
        <img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.9.1/img/item/{{match.stats.item6}}.png"/>
             <span ng-class ="{{match.stats.win}}">
             <p>{{champions[match.championId]}}</p>
             <p>{{match.subType}}</p>
             <p>{{match.lane}}</p>
             <p>{{match.stats.championsKilled}} Kills </p>
             <p>{{match.stats.numDeaths}} Deaths </p>
             <p>{{match.stats.assists}} Assists </p>
             </span>


        </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't assign true/false to ng-class itself, you assign classes based on expressions.

Assuming `match.stats.win` evaluates to true/false, here's how you can assign a conditional class using `ng-class`:

```
<span ng-class="{'winBg': match.stats.win, 'loseBg': !match.stats.win}">
```

This would assign the class `winBg` when `match.stats.win` evaluates to true, and class`loseBg` when it evaluates to false.

And then you can define your `winBg` and `loseBg` classes in your css, e.g.:

```
.winBg
{
    background-color: green;
}
.loseBg
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to switch from a span to a div cause of my mess up but this was spot on!!!!

Comment: @JacobHurley great :)